# Performing relate in ModelBuilder for one to many relationship?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, relates, one-to-many

I'm not sure how to do this as I don't' think there are any ModelBuilder tools for this task.  I'm not real savvy with Python but basically I want to relate field1 in table A to field2 in table B with a one to many relationship.  So I want all records in table B that match Table A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **[Add Join (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000064000000)** tool

> Joins a layer to another layer or table (where layer is a feature
>   layer, table view, or raster layer with a raster attribute table)
>   based on a common field.

This can be used in ModelBuilder and supports both one-to-one and many-to-one - if you need one-to-many you should be able to reverse the order of your inputs.

Comment: Hi PolyGeo, thank you for the response.  I should mention that I want a relate because I want to account for one to many relationships.  I don't believe a join will do this?

Comment: Done, sorry I should have been clear about that stipulation.

Answer (score 1):

"Map Rantala" came up with this when [Trying to perform “relate” in Model Builder](http://maprantala.com/index.php/2010/08/11/trying-to-perform-relate-in-model-builder/). It uses the Make Table tool to perform a relate like operation.