# Passing selection through relates in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, relationship-class, relates

I have a layer of facilities and a feature that has three related layers (Point, Area, Line). I'm trying to automate extracting data from the Line layer that's related to a selected set of facilities via relationship classes. I'm using Arcmap 10.3.

When I do this manually, I select all features in Facilities, open its attribute table then select the Facilities / Point relationship from a set of saved relationships. This opens the Point attribute table, which shows selected records related to the selected items in Facilities. Next, I select the Point / Area relationship, which opens the Area attribute table, also showing selected records. Finally, I select the Area / Line relationship. When that attribute table opens, it shows a selection of Line features that are related back to the selected Facilities features. From here, I can export the selected data from the Line layer.

I've created a model that runs successfully and creates all three relationships. The records in Facilities are selected but when I open the Line attribute table, none of them are.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: GIS_RelateModel_Q]

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing wrong is that this Create Relationship tool sets up a relationship (1:1, 1:M, or M:M) between the two tables. That is something that only needs to be done once, usually. What it seems you're wanting is a select pass-through from the 1 to the many file.

I've never done this in ModelBuilder, but you can start from this link:

[Performing relate in ModelBuilder for one to many relationship?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81294/performing-relate-in-modelbuilder-for-one-to-many-relationship?noredirect=1&lq=1)